# How to mutate without overwriting existing data in data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, economics

Below is the example data frame that I will be using. The difference column stands for price difference in time. For example, the price prediction in 2001 will be 6 + 3 = 9

| time | difference | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | NA | 6 |
| 2001 | 3 | NA |
| 2002 | 4 | NA |
| 2003 | 6 | NA |
| 2004 | -8 | NA |

Right now the code that I am using is below and it is not working since if I were to loop it, it would overwrite previous data when even I do so.

```
Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(new_price = difference + lag(new_price))
```

What I am looking for the a piece of code that can finish the list in one click, such that the expecting result would be

| time | difference | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | NA | 6 |
| 2001 | 3 | 9 |
| 2002 | 4 | 13 |
| 2003 | 6 | 19 |
| 2004 | -8 | 11 |

Any solution is welcomed and thank you guys very much.

Comment: You need ˋlag(price)ˋ  not. ˋ lag(new_price)ˋ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(time=c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005), diff=c(NA, 3, 4, 6, -8, 10), price=c(6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
dat2 <- dat %>% mutate(price=cumsum(coalesce(diff,price)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `accumulate` from `purrr`. You provide the vector of data (`diff` without the first element), the function `+` in this case, and an initial value which is the first value in `price`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(price = accumulate(diff[-1],
                            `+`,
                            .init = price[1]))
```

**Output**

```
  time diff price
1 2000   NA     6
2 2001    3     9
3 2002    4    13
4 2003    6    19
5 2004   -8    11
6 2005   10    21
```